# Repeat Pattern to 100% of the viewport

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, repeat, background-repeat

in CSS i made that code:

```
   body {
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    max-width:1920px;
    min-width:1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
```

but to seperate the header from the content i would like to have a "bar" between them.

so i made:

```
#zig {
max-width:100%;
background-image:url(../img/zig.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:25px;
```

but the Bar doesn't go "unlimited" it just repeat till it reaches "1920px" can i somehow change that? to put

```
min-width:100%
```

didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max-width:1920px; /* REMOVE ME */
```

if you want something to be max-width 1920 than use a container child (of body) element.

what way you #zag DIV will spann the full width of `html, body` which is dictated by the viewport width.

If #zag is a DIV (and it's not position absolute or fixed) than you need to set only it's height. `min-width:100%` is not needed since it already spans the full available width - being a block-level element.

```css
html,body{height:100%;}
body{margin:0; font:16px/1 sans-serif;}

header, section, footer{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;   /* you use 1920. 400 is for demo :) */
  background:#eee;
}

.zag{
  height: 50px;
  background:#0fb;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="zag">ZAG</div>
<section>SECTION</section>
<div class="zag">ZAG</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: Yes but what i meant is more like. Right now the seperation bar only Spans 1920px (if the viewport is bigger then there will be a aprubt end) but i want everything to be max. width 1920 EXCEPT that bar i want that one bar to be repeated even further

Comment: @MarcelSchulz read my answer. Than use (pseudo code:) `<BODY> <1920DIV /> <ZAG /> <1920DIV /> </BODY>`

Comment: So for example <body> <1920header> content </1920header> <zag/> ?

Comment: @MarcelSchulz yes. You got it right. So the point is that `body` should not have a 1920 px max-width. But rather those centered 1920header element.

Comment: Allright now i got it. then i'll have to order my CSS first. Thank you very much